# libpurple with PlayBook NDK

Tags: c, google-talk, libpurple, blackberry-playbook

My friend and I both have PlayBooks, and there isn't a solid Google Talk app on it.

We'd like to get started on one and I was wondering if anyone can provide any tips.

I was thinking of using libpurple as it is a C based library and the PlayBook NDK.

Is this feasible? Is there a recommended starting off point? And are there any general tips?

Thanks,

Parth

Comment: Is this feasible? Is there a recommended starting off point? And are there any general tips?

Answer (score 1):

The blackberry uses QNX platform which is based on Qt.

Currently libpurple does not interact with Qt. However there is a Google Summer of Code project to create a [Qt user interface](https://kingant.net/2013/05/four-pidgin-summer-of-code-students/) for libpurple. In theory once that work is completed then porting to the Playbook would be a short to medium task.

Comment: Sorry if this question is naiive, but can't I just use libpurple to establish the connection and get the buddy list, initiate chats, etc and then use qt to display the graphics>

Comment: The challenge is that libpurple uses glib's event loop system. Qt (and by extension QNX) has its own event loop at its core. Once the detail of that is sorted then yes using Qt for the display should be straight forward.